# How to calculate remaining value from array of object key?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object for input to ngx-pie-chart, I have to calculate the the total of values and form an object with remaining value.

```
a = [{name: "a", value: 50}
    {name: "b", value: 20}
    {name: "c", value: 0}
    {name: "d", value: 10}]

50+20+0+10 = 80
default = 100 - 80 = 20;

  result = [{name: "a", value: 50},
             {name: "b", value: 20},
             {name: "c", value: 0},
             {name: "d", value: 10},
             {name: "default", value: 20}]



   a.map(el => {        
    sum = sum + el.value;
    });
 default = 100 - sum;
a.push({name: 'default', value: default})
```

Comment: "default" is a reserved keyword in javascript, you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like so:

```js
const a = [
    {name: "a", value: 50},
    {name: "b", value: 20},
    {name: "c", value: 0},
    {name: "d", value: 10}
];

const result = [...a, {name: "default", value: 100 - a.reduce((acc, cur) => acc = acc + cur.value, 0)}]
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should using reduce instead of map.

```js
const a = [
    {name: "a", value: 50},
    {name: "b", value: 20},
    {name: "c", value: 0},
    {name: "d", value: 10}
];

const def = 100 - a.reduce((acc,el) => acc = acc+ el.value,0);
a.push({name: 'default', value: def})
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and elegant answer

```
const a = [{name: "a", value: 50},
    {name: "b", value: 20},
    {name: "c", value: 0},
    {name: "d", value: 10}]

const expectedResult = [{name: "a", value: 50},
             {name: "b", value: 20},
             {name: "c", value: 0},
             {name: "d", value: 10},
             {name: "default", value: 20}]

a.push(
    {
        name: "default",
        value: 100 - a.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc + curr.value), 0)
    }
);

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
  

    let a = [
        { name: "a", value: 50 },
        { name: "b", value: 20 },
        { name: "c", value: 0 },
        { name: "d", value: 10 },
      ];
    
      let sum = 0;
    
      a.map((el) => {
        sum += el.value;
      });
    
      const result= 100 - sum;
     
      const newValueToAdd= {
          name: "default",
          value: result,
       };
    
        a.push(newValueToAdd);
```